# Make ReflectionToStringBuilder skip fields with null values

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang

I have to print object values in log file. I used:

```
ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE, true, true);
```

But it also prints null values which I don't want to include, for instance:

> Pojo@117d9a3[id=1,**name=null**,description=Manchester United,KEY=APP-KEY,secretKey=Alex ]

How to suppress null values from being included?

Comment: Did you try creating your own custom `ToStringStyle`?

Comment: I am not sure how to create and implement custom ToStringStyle format..Can you give me some example with implementation for Custom format

Answer (score 19):

A simpler solution without subclassing would be to override the accept method:

```
public String toStringWithAttributes() {

    Object myself = this;
    ReflectionToStringBuilder builder = new ReflectionToStringBuilder(
            this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE) {

            @Override
            protected boolean accept(Field field) {
                try {
                    return super.accept(field) && field.get(myself) != null;
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    return super.accept(field);
                }
            }

    };

    return builder.toString();

}
```

This has the added benefit that you can use whatever `ToStringStyle` you want and the formatting is otherwise perfect.

Comment: How do you extend the exemption to also a value i.e. `field.get(myself) != 0.0` also

Answer (score 6):

You have to provide your own ToStringStyle implementation. Something like this (untested!):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ToStringStyle;

public final class NotNullToStringStyle extends ToStringStyle {
    public static final ToStringStyle NOT_NULL_STYLE = new NotNullToStringStyle();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * <p>Constructor.</p>
     *
     * <p>Use the static constant rather than instantiating.</p>
     */
    NotNullToStringStyle() {
        super();
        this.setContentStart("[");
        this.setFieldSeparator(SystemUtils.LINE_SEPARATOR + "  ");
        this.setFieldSeparatorAtStart(true);
        this.setContentEnd(SystemUtils.LINE_SEPARATOR + "]");
    }

    /**
     * <p>Ensure <code>Singleton</code> after serialization.</p>
     *
     * @return the singleton
     */
    private Object readResolve() {
        return NOT_NULL_STYLE;
    }

    @Override
    public void append(StringBuffer buffer, String fieldName, Object value, Boolean fullDetail) {
        if (value != null) {
            appendFieldStart(buffer, fieldName);
            appendInternal(buffer, fieldName, value, isFullDetail(fullDetail));
            appendFieldEnd(buffer, fieldName);
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the code is copied from `MultiLineToStringStyle`, since it's `private` and `final` so we can't extend it. The real thing happens in the `append` method. Here is the original one for reference:

```
    public void append(StringBuffer buffer, String fieldName, Object value, Boolean fullDetail) {
        appendFieldStart(buffer, fieldName);

        if (value == null) {
            appendNullText(buffer, fieldName);

        } else {
            appendInternal(buffer, fieldName, value, isFullDetail(fullDetail));
        }

        appendFieldEnd(buffer, fieldName);
    }
```

Comment: If its not extends,how do i implement.I tried remove final also.Its not work. Pls explain me how do i implement this scenario.

Comment: The class `NotNullToStringStyle` already implements this. You just have to use it like this: `ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, NotNullToStringStyle.NOT_NULL_STYLE, true, true)`

Comment: the main benefit of this approach is code reuse across several POJOs. The main drawback is that you're tied to a single style, while, if you extend `ReflectionToStringBuilder`, you can skip nulls while using whichever style.

Answer (score 5):

Out of the box implementation exists from Apache commons-lang3:

*ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(new Pojo(), ToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE, true,
false, **true**, null)*

Output is as requested:

```
general.Pojo@3532ec19[description=Manchester,id=1]
```

Using:
*public static  String toString(
final T object, final ToStringStyle style, final boolean outputTransients,
final boolean outputStatics, final boolean **excludeNullValues**, final Class<? super T> reflectUpToClass)*

Answer (score 2):

[@Christian Sporer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41218819/631272) (go upvote him), but modified to be a reusable util method:

```java
public class ToStringUtil {
  public static String toStringWithAttributes(Object ofInterest, ToStringStyle style) { 
    ReflectionToStringBuilder builder = new ReflectionToStringBuilder(ofInterest, style) { 
      @Override
      protected boolean accept(Field field) {
        try { return super.accept(field) && field.get(ofInterest) != null; }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) { return super.accept(field); }
      }
    };
    return builder.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: It was just too big/ugly to be a comment on his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.6, there is a built in method

```
ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this, ToStringStyle.DEFAULT_STYLE,false,false,true,null);
```

The method signature is:

```
ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(
   Object object, 
   ToStringStyle style, 
   boolean outputTransients, 
   boolean outputStatics, 
   boolean excludeNullValues, 
   Class<? super Object> reflectUpToClass)
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a way Create new ToStringStyle object call `setNullText(String nullText)` on this object with your own text, then pass this ToStringStyle object into constructor of the `ReflectionToStringBuilder` class.